# redireccionar a una pagina de salida envio exitosos formulario php

Tags: php, formularios

Buenos días tengo un formulario de contacto **PHP** funcionando pero a la hora de enviar el mesaje de éxito de envio me redirecciona a una pagina en blanco , como podría hacer para que me llevase a una pagina propia de formulario tipo: `formulario-éxito.html`   enviado con éxito.

este es el código que  tiene el formulario al final preconfigurado

```
<?php 
  if(isset($_POST['email'])){

    $name =$_POST["name"];
    $from =$_POST["email"];
    $phone=$_POST["phone"];
    $comment=$_POST["comment"];
    $budget=$_POST["budget"];

    // Email Receiver Address
    $receiver="abc@gmail.es";
    $subject="Consulta a traves de formulario de contacto de Voy a Defenderte";

    $message = "
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>HTML email</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table width='50%' border='0' align='center' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
    <tr>
    <td colspan='2' align='center' valign='top'><img style=' margin-top: 15px; ' src='http://www.ociodinamicomultimedia.es/maquetas/voy/images/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png' ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width='50%' align='right'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align='left'>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align='right' valign='top' style='border-top:1px solid #dfdfdf; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#000; padding:7px 5px 7px 0;'>Nombre:</td>
    <td align='left' valign='top' style='border-top:1px solid #dfdfdf; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#000; padding:7px 0 7px 5px;'>".$name."</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align='right' valign='top' style='border-top:1px solid #dfdfdf; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#000; padding:7px 5px 7px 0;'>Email:</td>
    <td align='left' valign='top' style='border-top:1px solid #dfdfdf; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#000; padding:7px 0 7px 5px;'>".$from."</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align='right' valign='top' style='border-top:1px solid #dfdfdf; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#000; padding:7px 5px 7px 0;'>Teléfono:</td>
    <td align='left' valign='top' style='border-top:1px solid #dfdfdf; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#000; padding:7px 0 7px 5px;'>".$phone."</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align='right' valign='top' style='border-top:1px solid #dfdfdf; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#000; padding:7px 5px 7px 0;'>Reclamación Sobre:</td>
    <td align='left' valign='top' style='border-top:1px solid #dfdfdf; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#000; padding:7px 0 7px 5px;'>".$budget."</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align='right' valign='top' style='border-top:1px solid #dfdfdf; border-bottom:1px solid #dfdfdf; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#000; padding:7px 5px 7px 0;'>Consulta:</td>
    <td align='left' valign='top' style='border-top:1px solid #dfdfdf; border-bottom:1px solid #dfdfdf; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#000; padding:7px 0 7px 5px;'>".nl2br($comment)."</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
    ";
// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <'.$from.'>' . "\r\n";
   if(mail($receiver,$subject,$message,$headers))  
   {
       //Success Message
      echo "Su mensaje fue enviado con éxito! En breve nos pondremos en contacto.";
   }
   else
   {    
     //Fail Message
      echo "Su mensaje no pudo ser enviado!";
   }

}
?>
```

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar:

- **header** cambia la URL a otra que le pases como parámetro.
- **file_get_contents** en la misma página te muestra el contendio.

**Ejemplo**

[header](http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php)

```
header("Location: https://www.example.com/formulario-exito.html"); /
exit();
```

Para obtener el contenido de la pagina sin redireccionar, puedes usar:
[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
$pag= file_get_contents('https://www.example.com/formulario-exito.html');
    echo $pag;
    exit();
```

o

```
$pag= file_get_contents('formulario-exito.html');
    echo $pag;
    exit();
```

Comment: Entonces sustiuyo el código que tiene ahora la pagina de// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <'.$from.'>' . "\r\n";
   if(mail($receiver,$subject,$message,$headers))  
   {
    //Success Message
      echo "Su mensaje fue enviado con éxito! En breve nos pondremos en contacto.";
   }
   else
   { 
     //Fail Message
      echo "Su mensaje no pudo ser enviado!";
   }

}
?>        por el de header o como hago ?

Answer (score 0):

Todavía no puedo poner comentarios por lo que te contesto con una respuesta:
Si funciona y envía el email al contacto, entonces, lo que debes sustituir son los echo de "Su mensaje..." por la anterior respuesta:

```
header("Location: https://www.example.com/formulario-exito.html"); /
exit();
```

Y en caso de fallo, por ejemplo, la misma url con una query-string para indicar si el mensaje se envió bien o no:

```
header("Location: https://www.example.com/formulario-exito.html?envio=mal"); /
exit();
```